# Overlay legend on graph area with GGPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to overlay the legend on the graph area with GGPlot? The legend is set be default to the left of the graph area, but I would like to position it like the figure shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[ggplot2 documentation on the subject](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html) `plot+theme(legend.position = c(.5, .5))`with the appropriate coordinates should do it.

Comment: This is more like a comment, also the post was marked as duplicate, avoid answering dupe posts.